# Existence of matrix cycling through a given basis

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

Let $(v_1, \ldots , v_n)$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. An exercise I gave myself was to show that for $n$ odd, there exists a unique matrix $M$ sending $v_1$ to $v_2, \ldots, v_{n-1}$ to $v_n$ and $v_n$ to $v_1$. Essentially $M$ acts as a cycle on the basis. And for $n$ even, $M$ would swap $v_1$ and $v_2$, $v_3$ and $v_4$, $\ldots,$ $v_{n-1}$ and $v_n$.

Focusing on the case where $n$ is odd, all I was able to show was that if $M$ actually exists, it would have determinant $1$, have all eigenvalues $1$ with algebraic multiplicity $n$, and have eigenvector $v_1 + \ldots + v_n$ with geometric multiplicity $1$. But I am struggling to show it exists or even construct examples, besides the symmetric matrix cycling the standard basis.

Does such a matrix exists? Are the partial results above even correct? I would appreciate any hints for this exercise.

Comment: A way you might like to think about it is that if $M$ cycles the standard basis in the way you want, and if $P$ is the change-of-basis matrix sending the standard basis to your basis (ie $P$ has columns $v_i$), then $PMP^{-1}$ is a matrix that multiplies vectors with components with respect to the standard basis in the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you have that if $B$ is a basis for a vector space $V$ then for each function $f:B\rightarrow V$ there is exactly one linear map $g:V\rightarrow V$ such that $g(b)=f(b)$ for all elements of the basis.

You can get the matrix for such a transform by just writing the images of the basis column by column. So in this case each column will have excatly one $1$.

Although I can say that the kind of matrix you are talking about is called a permutation matrix, and you are indeed correct that in this case the determinant is $1$ if $n$ is odd and $-1$ if $n$ is even.

Comment: If $M$ is forced to be a permutation matrix, wouldn't the basis be forced to consist of vectors of the form $(a_1, \ldots , a_n) , (a_2, \ldots , a_n, a_1)$, etc?

Comment: the basis doesn't matter the matrix is supposed to be in terms of the matric

Comment: Okay I see, to be sure I understand, because of the existence and uniqueness of $g$, the matrix $M$ I want exists and is unique? For both of the cases ($n$ even or odd)?

Comment: yeah it's unique, you can always define a matrix that does whatever you want to the basis, and it is unieque. The idea is that the function is defined for any lineal combination of the elements is defined because of lineality.